# Can boost spirit scan a syntax tree and produce results?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, code-generation, boost-spirit

I want to write a small language and i decided to use [Boost Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/). It looks fine for me. I know i can use spirit to write a lexer, and a parser to create a syntax tree. Is it possible in Spirit to scan the syntax tree and produce results. (or is it just for parsing?) Are there available functions to generate the results or do i have to use a different tool? Sorry for this easy question, but i really couldn't find information while looking at Spirit documentation briefly.

In addition to this, can i use my own lexer with a parser written using Spirit.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, this would really be a candidate for 'not a real question'. Had you not linked to the docs page, I'd have dismissed it with just that link.

As it happens, perhaps you have missed the samples:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/
- many versions of a simple expression calculator (perhaps look at them in sequential order)
- conjure compiler
  This compiler is capable of compiling - and running - a simple language. Samples [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/conjure_samples):

  ```
  /* The factorial (in conjure) */

  int factorial(n)
  {
      if (n <= 0)
          return 1;
      else
          return n * factorial(n-1);
  }

  int main(n)
  {
      return factorial(n);
  }
  ```

- There is also a [`mini C` compiler sample](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/mini_c/)

---

**Q.** In addition to this, can i use my own lexer with a parser written using Spirit?

**A.** Yes. Just expose a token iterator interface, and use that as input iterators to the parse API. See the examples with Spirit Lex for more information.

Comment: thanks, the content of links are exaclty what i was looking for.